# Prove that 3 circumcircles derived from a triangle are concurrent

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

$P,Q,R$ are points on the sides of    $\triangle{ABC}$   $BC,CA,AB$ respectively.$B-P-C$,$C-Q-A$, $A-R-B$. Prove that circumcircles of $\triangle{AQR}, \triangle{BRP}, \triangle{CPQ}$ passes through one point.

I know this is something related to [Miquel point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MiquelPoint.html). But I don't know how to apply that.

[image]

Comment: What does $\;B-P-C\;$ , etc. , mean here??

Comment: Points B,P,C are col-linear and p is between B and C

Comment: Wasn't that already clear from "P,Q,R points *on the sides of* ..." ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: The notation probably indicates *betweenness*, since the proof is more-straightforward in this case. As mentioned in the [Wikipedia "Miquel's Theorem" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miquel%27s_theorem), you can take $M$ to be the ("other") intersection of two of the circles (say, the ones through $A$ and $B$); the two cyclic quadrilaterals $\square AQMR$ and $\square BRMP$ have angle measures $A^\prime := 180^\circ - A$ and $B^\prime := 180^\circ - B$ at $M$. Therefore, $\square CPMQ$ has measure $360^\circ - A^\prime - B^\prime = 180^\circ - C$ at $M$, making it cyclic.